# Ionic 2 disable specific button inside list

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a list generated by an *ngfor, inside each item there is a button.
I want to disable  only 1 item button, when i try to disable a button all buttons in each item get disabled.

.html

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of list">
          <button color="app ionbutton (click)="disable()" [disabled]="isDisabled">button</button>
         </ion-item>
```

.ts

```
isDisabled=false;
disable(){this.isDisabled=true;}
```

Answer (score 0):

All the buttons are binded to the same variable so yes, they will all be disabled.
To solve your problem you can bind the value to an attribute of your item :

```
list : any[] = [{itemId : 1, disabled : false},{itemId : 2, disabled : false},{itemId : 3, disabled : false}]

constructor(){}

disable(item) {
  item.disable = true;
}
```

And in your template :

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of list">
          <button color="app ionbutton (click)="disable(item)" [disabled]="item.disabled">button</button>
</ion-item>
```